# Commenting out unwated CSS/scripts in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, comments, html

I am trying to comment out unwanted CSS and JS files to prevent them from firing in the HTML by creating a simple function in my functions.php. So far I have:

```
function commentStuff() {
$stylesheet = "<link rel=stylesheet --unwanted CSS file-- />";
$CommentedStyle = '<!-- ' . $stylesheet . ' -->';

return $CommentedStyle;
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working as I am hoping.

I am trying to find ways to allow my friend's website to run faster, and noticed there are several unnecessary CSS and scripts that load automatically. I have blocked some of these from triggering in the plugin/theme files by commenting them out, but a better way to get the same results without having to dig through files would be to just comment out the unwanted CSS and scripts in the HTML from my functions.php.

I have tried using echo instead of return with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) to show your scripts and styles (`#qm-assets`) - specifically the ID used to register the scripts/styles.

Then hook [`wp_print_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts) and use [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) to remove it before it outputs.

```
/**
 * Dequeue the jQuery UI script.
 *
 * Hooked to the wp_print_scripts action, with a late priority (100),
 * so that it is after the script was enqueued.
 */
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

---

You can also wrap your [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) with [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) (PRI `0`) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) (PRI [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max)) to run [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) if you know the exact output.

Answer (score 0):

This is generaly a long term bad idea equivalent to forking the plugin even if you don't change a single line of code in them as the plugin might require those commented out styles/scripts in its next version (or your freind will change setting that require it).

If you are not happy with how the plugin works, contact his author and ask them to fix it, otherwise if it is really important just use another one or actually make a full blown fork of it, changing its name so it will not be updated by mistake.